# Android Listview row is affecting other rows

Tags: listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am running with an odd issue for few days. Googled about it and also searched in stack overflow. But still I am not figure out where its going wrong. 
Kindly help me to fix this.

**Context** Android ListView with custom adapter is misbehaving

**Background** There is a listview having two item (TextView and ImageView) in every row. I want to change background color of textview on click of row.

**Problem** Clicking on row is also changing background color of one more row.

**My Analysis** In my screen there are 7 rows(out of 10) in visible state. When I am clicking the first row its changing color of two rows. Row no 1 and Row no 8. It seems after every 7 rows again its counting it from 1. Really don't know whats happening. Here is code.

**Custom Adapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<BOQuestion> {
int layoutResourceID;
Context context;
List<BOQuestion> allQuestion;

public CustomAdapter1(Context context, int resource,
        List<BOQuestion> allQuestion) {
    super(context, resource, allQuestion);
    layoutResourceID = resource;
    this.context = context;
    this.allQuestion = allQuestion;
}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvQuestion;
    public ImageView ivMore;
}

@Override
public BOQuestion getItem(int position) {
    return allQuestion.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceID, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvQuestion = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
        holder.ivMore = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.i_more);
        holder.tvQuestion.setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    BOQuestion oneQuestion = getItem(position);
    holder.tvQuestion.setText(oneQuestion.getQuestion());
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.tvQuestion.setBackgroundColor(R.color.light_gray);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
    }
}
```